# Cotangent map is not surjective

Tags: algebraic-geometry

This is Vakil 19.1 B, self-study.

We have to show that the normalization of the cusp at the tacnode:

$$\operatorname{Spec} k[t] \to \operatorname{Spec} k[x, y]/(y^2 - x^4)$$

given by $x \mapsto t^2, y \mapsto t^4$ does not have an injective tangent map at closed points.

Here is what I have so far: this is equivalent to not having a surjective contangent map at closed points. If we choose the closed point $(x, y)$ in the image, this is mapped to by $(t)$. The residue fields are both $k$, so the cotangent map makes sense.

I believe the cotangent map is then a map

$$(x, y)/(x, y)^2 \to (t)/(t)^2$$

but the problem is I do not know what this map actually does, and to be honest, I am not sure I ever did. How do I proceed from here?

Comment: The map is the one that sends $x\mapsto t^2$ and $y\mapsto t^4$. This is kind of the only thing that could ever happen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's more intuitive to first think about the tangent map. At a point $t_0 \in \mathbb{A}^1$ it is literally given by the derivative of the polynomial function $t \mapsto (t^2, t^4)$, which means it is $(2t_0, 4t_0^3)$, and in particular it vanishes at the origin (but not at any other point).

The cotangent map is the infinitesimal version of pullback of regular functions so at the origin it sends $f(x, y) \in (x, y)/(x, y)^2$ to $f(t^2, t^4) \in t/t^2$. If $f(x, y) = ax + by + \text{higher terms}$ then $f(t^2, t^4) = at^2 + \text{higher terms}$ vanishes in $t/t^2$.