# (Co)tangent Map of the d^th Veronese Embedding

Tags: algebraic-geometry

This question is regarding Vakil 19.1 D, self-study.

What does the (co)tangent map of the $d^{th}$ Veronese embedding over an algebraically closed field $k$

$$\mathbb P^n_k \to \mathbb P^N_k$$

look like on closed points? Specifically, I would like to see the tangent map is injective (or the cotangent map is surjective). If we choose a closed point in $\mathbb P^N_k$ and look at it inside an affine patch, we get a residue field that looks like (say in $U_0$)

$$k[y_1,...,y_N]/(y_1-a_1,...,y_N-a_N)$$

where we think of the $y_i$ as degree $d$ monomials in the $x_i$ divided by $x_0^d$. This maps to $k[x_1,...,x_n]/(x_1-a_1,...,x_n-a_n)$ by (I think) sending each $y_i$ to the corresponding monomial in the $x_i$. The cotangent map appears to be

$$(y_1-a_1,...,y_N-a_N)/(y_1-a_1,...,y_N-a_N)^2 \to (x_1-a_1,...,x_n-a_n)/(x_1-a_1,...,x_n-a_n)^2$$

sending the $y_i$ to the same monomials as above, and keeping the constants fixed. How is this onto? What maps to $x_i-a_i$ for a fixed $i$, for example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As in your [previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3973312/cotangent-map-is-not-surjective/3973375#3973375) I continue to think it is more intuitive to look at the tangent map. The Veronese embedding can be written in a coordinate-free way as

$$\mathbb{P}(V) \ni [v] \mapsto [v^n] \in \mathbb{P}(S^n(V))$$

where $V$ is a finite-dimensional vector space and $S^n(V)$ is its $n^{th}$ [symmetric power](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_algebra). The [Zariski tangent space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zariski_tangent_space) at a point $[v] \in \mathbb{P}(V)$ can naturally be identified with the quotient $V/v$ of $V$ by the subspace spanned by $v$. Writing a tangent vector at $[v]$ in the form $[v + \epsilon w]$ where $\epsilon^2 = 0$, the differential of the Veronese embedding is

$$[v + \epsilon] \mapsto [(v + \epsilon w)^n] = \left[ v^n + n \epsilon wv^{n-1} \right] \in \mathbb{P}(S^n(V))$$

so to show injectivity it suffices to show that if $nw v^{n-1} = 0$ in the tangent space $S^n(V)/v^n$ to $v^n$, then $w = 0$ in $V/v$. If the characteristic of $k$ does not divide $n$, so that we can divide by $n$, this follows from the fact that the symmetric algebra $S(V) = \sum_{n \ge 0} S^n(V)$, which is a polynomial algebra, is an integral domain, so if $wv^{n-1} = c v^n$ then $v^{n-1}$ can be canceled from both sides to give $w = cv$.

If the characteristic of $k$ does divide $n$ then this definition of the Veronese embedding differs from the one using monomials. I assume that whatever source this came from is implicitly working in characteristic $0$. It may be possible to rescue this version of the Veronese embedding using [divided powers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divided_power_structure).

**Edit:** Here is some detail on the identification of the Zariski tangent space at $v$ with $V/v$, as requested. Working slightly informally (every manipulation I'm doing with infinitesimals can be justified by defining the Zariski tangent space using $k[\epsilon]/\epsilon^2$ but I have not done so here), consider the quotient map

$$V \setminus \{ 0 \} \ni v \mapsto [v] \in \mathbb{P}(V).$$

Since $V$ is a vector space the Zariski tangent space at every point can be canonically identified with $V$. The differential of the quotient map at $v \in V$ sends a tangent vector $v + \epsilon w$ to $[v + \epsilon w]$. The kernel of the differential consists of $\epsilon w$ such that $[v + \epsilon w] = [v]$, meaning $v + \epsilon w$ is a scalar multiple of $v$, meaning $w$ is a scalar multiple of $v$. And the differential is surjective (I don't know what the cleanest way to see this is but it follows from working in an affine chart of $\mathbb{P}(V)$). So it identifies the tangent space at $[v]$ with $V/v$ as desired.

**Edit #2:** As Georges says in the comments, this identification of the Zariski tangent space is not quite right; it should be $\text{Hom}(v, V/v)$ where $v$ is shorthand for the line spanned by $v$. I neglected to take into account the effect of scaling $v$ properly. However, if we pick a specific $v \in V$ lifting $[v] \in \mathbb{P}(V)$ we can ignore this which is implicitly what I've done above so the calculations above are still fine (as far as I can tell).

Comment: Can you elaborate on why the tangent space is V/v?

Comment: @Johnny: the argument was slightly too long for a comment so I've edited it into the answer. I've also slightly modified my notation so that $\epsilon$ is now consistently an infinitesimal scalar; sorry for the confusion.

Comment: I'm evidently not ready for an answer line this. I don't know differentials, and I do not understand the statement "the Zariski tangent space at every point of V is V because V is a vector space." All I know is that the Zariski tangent space is the dual of m/m^2, where m is the maximal ideal of the stalk at the point of consideration.

Comment: @Johnny: differentials work more or less the same way they do in calculus, which is why I prefer to think about things this way. As for the fact about Zariski tangent spaces: $V$ acts transitively on itself (by which I mean on its $k$-points) so we can work at the origin WLOG. The ring of regular functions on $V$ is the symmetric algebra $S(V^{\ast})$ of the dual of $V$. The maximal ideal $m$ cutting out the origin is the ideal $S_{\ge 1}(V^{\ast})$ of polynomials with no constant term, and $m^2$ is the ideal $S_{\ge 2}(V^{\ast})$ of polynomials with no constant or linear term, so...

Comment: ...$m/m^2$ can canonically be identified with $V^{\ast}$, and so its dual can canonically be identified with $V$. The point *intuitively* is that tangent vectors are supposed to be points "infinitesimally close" to a given point (and this intuition can be made precise), and in a vector space if $w$ is infinitesimally close to $v$ then $ w - v$ is a vector infinitesimally close to $0$. Thinking about the usual smooth tangent spaces of $\mathbb{R}^n$ (which can also canonically be identified with $\mathbb{R}^n$) may be helpful here.

Comment: All of this can be converted into coordinates if desired but it would be long and kind of annoying, although it would have the benefit of working in positive characteristic. If you haven't done so, it would be a good exercise to compute the (co)differential of an arbitrary polynomial map $\mathbb{A}^n \to \mathbb{A}^m$ and verify that 1) it is just the ordinary differential you are familiar with from calculus and 2) it can be computed by inserting infinitesimals squaring to zero into the inputs.

Comment: There is a lot to say here I guess. The annoying thing, as I see it, with working with the explicit form of the Veronese embedding in coordinates is that it's not clear *a priori* how it transforms under change of coordinates, and without the freedom to change coordinates you lose the freedom to assume WLOG that you are working at, say, the point $(0 : 0 : \dots : 1)$, which makes the formulas messier.

Comment: Alright, I understand your argument for the tangent space of V at a k-point. I think all I am not understanding is why your tangent vectors look like $v + \epsilon w$. If you look at Vakil 12.1 I, I would have guessed it would be $v + c\epsilon$, where $c \in k$.

Comment: @Johnny: I changed my notation so that $\epsilon$ is an infinitesimal scalar and $w \in V$. This means $v + \epsilon w \in V \otimes k[\epsilon]/\epsilon^2$ (which is the rigorous setting for this infinitesimal stuff). Formally, for an affine variety $X$, a pair consisting of a $k$-point of $X$ and a Zariski tangent vector at that point turns out to be the same thing as a morphism $\text{Spec } k[\epsilon/\epsilon^2] \to X$ (of affine schemes) and this is the fact I'm implicitly using to set things up.

Comment: Dear Qiaochu, your description of the tangent space to $\mathbb P(V)$ at the point $[v]=k.v\in \mathbb P(V)$ as being canonically isomorphic to $V/[v]$ is not correct. A correct canonical isomorphism is $T_{[v]}\mathbb P(V)= L_{ k-\operatorname {lin}}([v],V/[v])$.This is stated and proved (in the more general case of a Grassmannian) on page 201 of Harris's [*Algebraic Geometry* A First course](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9780387977164).

Comment: @Georges: whoops, my apologies. In that case I'm confused about what exactly goes wrong with the argument I sketched but I guess I'll think about it.

Comment: Oh, no need to apologize, Qiaochu: who can claim never to have been absent-minded?